# Python request with authenticated proxy without exposing username and password.

Tags: python, http-proxy

I am using request library to connect to an api and get data. I have the proxy to connect and it works with  [AuthenticatedProxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34079/how-to-specify-an-authenticated-proxy-for-a-python-http-connection/3942980#3942980)

This is how my code looks.

```
import requests
s = requests.Session()
url = "https://testapi"
urlkey = “testkey”
proxies = {'https': 'http://<UserName>:<Password>@proxy_url:8080'}
resp = s.get(url, params={'key':urlkey }, proxies = proxies)
content = resp.content
print content
```

Username and Password is exposed here and I want to avoid that. How can I acheived that ? Can i ask request to use defaultCredentials or 'account that is running the python script' credentials ?

In .net,  following config works:

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
      <proxy proxyaddress="https://testapi:8080" bypassonlocal="True"/>
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
```

Thanks all. 
Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35746251/making-python-requests-using-a-proxy-without-specifying-username-and-password-u).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `request` [docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#proxies):

> You can also configure proxies by setting the environment variables
>   HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY.

So you could avoid revealing the credentials in the script by setting the environment variable instead:

```
$ export HTTPS_PROXY="http://<UserName>:<Password>@proxy_url:8080"
```

And then in the script you would use the proxy by just calling:

```
resp = s.get(url, params={'key':urlkey })
```

Comment: Thanks @TheoretiCAL. However I am not sure if I am allowed to to set HTTPS_PROXY in my production environment.

Comment: @ProgSky Have you considered prompting for the credentials when running the script instead? See https://docs.python.org/2/library/getpass.html. Alternatively, you can use a python .net wrapper, and this will give you access to system.net calls. https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet